# jQuery Autocomplete - Override label / value in source data

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

It appears that the autocomplete widget requires the data to have variables 'label' and 'value' in the array.

Is it possible to override this and use your own values (such as columns from a db) so you can have more than one text box with autocomplete in a form?

A couple of tips for anyone using autocomplete with PHP and MySQL...

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomerLookup)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

gets the data in json format out the DB

```
select: function( event, ui ) { 
    $( "#name" ).val(ui.item.name);
    $( "#surname" ).val(ui.item.surname);
    $( "#company" ).val(ui.item.company);
    $( "#address1" ).val(ui.item.address1);
    $( "#address2" ).val(ui.item.address2);
     etc
```

fills other text boxes with data if you are aiming to fill an entire form from one autocompleting textbox

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the `value` to the database ID of the record. You can then take that `value` (which is the database ID) and get `name`, `surname`, `company` etc..

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I could re-write the DB column names when I create the array so that whatever the database ID column is named becomes 'label' and the value column I want is renamed 'value'. Just wish I could tell the javascript what values to use in the json data without editing the source of the jquery widget (which is currently what I'm doing)

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://goo.gl/tm58m)

```js
<script> 
$().ready(function() {
$('#tag').autocomplete('tag.php?find=tag', {
          width: 260,
          matchContains: true,
          selectFirst: false
        });
});

    $('#other').autocomplete('tag.php?find=other', {
          width: 260,
          matchContains: true,
          selectFirst: false
        });
});
</script>
```

```php
<?php
//in tag.php
$find = $_GET["find"];
if($find=='tag'){
    $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
    if (!$q) return;
    $sql = "select DISTINCT tag from tag where name_tag LIKE '%$q%'";
    $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
        $cname = $rs['name_tag'];
        echo "$cname\n";
    }
}
/*
This adds to other data
    if($find=='other'){
    $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
    if (!$q) return;
    $sql = "select DISTINCT tag from tag where name_tag LIKE '%$q%'";
    $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
        $cname = $rs['name_tag'];
        echo "$cname\n";
    }
}
*/
?>
```

```html
<input id='tag' type='text'>
<input id='other' type='text'>
```